# Duplicate objects stored in array while adding an element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am developing an application in angular as a beginner. The application takes notes and stores them in DB.

I am facing an issue during addition. If there are no existing data in DB and I have added two new notes, both the notes are displayed as same in UI. Although the new note and old note is present in DB.

[image]

I observed one thing. The data returned from DB is in JSON format.
On adding new data, the note array is displayed as -

```
0: {}
1: {}
2: Note{}
3: Note{}
```

NoteService -

```
export class NotesService {

  private baseURL = 'http://localhost:8082/api/v1/note';
  notes: Note[];
  notesSubject: BehaviorSubject<Note[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.notes = [];
    this.notesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Note[]>([]);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body;
  }

  fetchNotesFromServer(): Observable<Note[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/${sessionStorage.getItem("userId")}`)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
    ;
  }

  getNotes(): BehaviorSubject<Note[]> {
    this.fetchNotesFromServer().subscribe(
      notes => { this.notes = notes; this.notesSubject.next(this.notes) },
      error => this.handleErrorObservable(error));
    return this.notesSubject;
  }

  addNote(note: Note): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, note, { observe: 'response' });
  }

  private handleErrorObservable(error: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);

    return Observable.throw(new HttpErrorResponse(error));
  }
}
```

NoteTakerComponent : addNote() -

```
addNote(): void {
        this.errMessage = '';
        if (this.validateNote()) {
          this.note.noteCreatedBy = sessionStorage.getItem("userId");
          this.note.noteTitle = this.noteTitle;
          this.note.noteContent = this.noteContent;
          this.note.noteStatus = this.state;
          this.note.category = this.editCategory;
          this.note.reminder = this.editReminder;
          let maxId = 0;
          if (this.noteService.notes.length > 0) {
            this.noteService.notes.forEach(note => {
              if (note.noteId > maxId) {
                maxId = note.noteId;
              }
            });
          }
          this.note.noteId = ++maxId;
          this.noteService.addNote(this.note).subscribe(response => {
            this.noteService.notes.push(this.note);
            this.noteService.notesSubject.next(this.noteService.notes);
            console.log('note taker', this.noteService.notes);
            this.reset();
          },
            error => this.handleErrorResponse(error));
        }
      }
```

NoteTaker view -

```
<!-- Expansion panel to add new notes -->
<div class="keep-note-expansion-panel">
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>Take a note</mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <div class="keep-note-form-container">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput class="note-full-width form-control" name="title" placeholder="title" [(ngModel)]="noteTitle"
            required>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <textarea matInput class="note-full-width form-control" name="text" placeholder="text"
            [(ngModel)]="noteContent" required></textarea>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select name="Status" placeholder="Select state" [(ngModel)]="state">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">
              {{ state }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select name="category" placeholder="Select Category" [(ngModel)]="editCategory">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">
              {{ category.categoryName }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select name="reminder" placeholder="Select Reminder" [(ngModel)]="editReminder" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let reminder of reminders" [value]="reminder">
              {{ reminder.reminderName }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <button mat-button (click)="addNote()">Done</button>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

NoteView Component -

```
 export class NoteViewComponent implements OnInit {
  notes: Note[];
  errorMessage: String;
  constructor(private noteService: NotesService) {

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.noteService.getNotes().subscribe(
      notes => {
        this.notes = notes;
        console.log('note view', this.notes);
      },
      error => this.handleErrorResponse(error));
  }

}
```

Expected result is to show newly added notes with the old notes.

Comment: What's your problem? I don't get it at the moment.

Comment: Hi. I need to see the note-taker.component.html. another question: why do you use notes and notesSubject on the service to do the same thing? I think the notesSubject may be enough to save the values and let components communicate. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Batajus - I have attached a screenshot where you can find duplicate notes. Although I had added initially Note 1 and then Note 2.

I have added the note taker view and note view component as well. Please suggest what modifications are required.

Answer (score 0):

There was a basic error where the same note object was modified instead of creating a new object.

Modified NoteTaker component -

```
addNote(): void {
    this.errMessage = '';
    this.note = new Note();
    if (this.validateNote()) {
      this.note.noteCreatedBy = sessionStorage.getItem("userId");
      this.note.noteTitle = this.noteTitle;
      this.note.noteContent = this.noteContent;
      this.note.noteStatus = this.state;
      this.note.category = this.editCategory;
      this.note.reminder = this.editReminder;
      let maxId = 0;
      if (this.noteService.notes.length > 0) {
        this.noteService.notes.forEach(note => {
          if (note.noteId > maxId) {
            maxId = note.noteId;
          }
        });
      }
      this.note.noteId = ++maxId;
      this.noteService.addNote(this.note).subscribe(response => {
        this.noteService.notes.push(this.note);
        this.noteService.notesSubject.next(this.noteService.notes);
        console.log('note taker', this.noteService.notes);
        this.reset();
      },
        error => this.handleErrorResponse(error));
    }
  }
```